# Git add command and Permission denied on files

Tags: git

in my project i try to pull from git server. after some changes i add and then commit but when i want to add i get this message

```
PS D:\Projects\NAPServer> git add *
server/log/log/dashboardAppLog.log: Permission denied
PS D:\Projects\NAPServer>
```

when i try to push i get this message:

```
PS D:\Projects\NAPServer> git push origin master
To http://192.168.1.201:80/Bonobo.Git.Server/NAPServer.git
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'http://192.168.1.201:80/Bonobo.Git.Server/NAPServer.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
PS D:\Projects\NAPServer>
```

i try to pull but it doesn't work.i cant remove or rename file.

**UPDATE**

my git status is :

```
PS D:\Projects\NAPServer> git status
server/log/log/dashboardAppLog.log: Permission denied
On branch master
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 4 and 7 different commits each, respectively.
 (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

nothing to commit, working directory clean
PS D:\Projects\NAPServer>
```

Comment: What does `git status` show you?

Comment: Sholdn't it be git add .? Or for the newest version, git add -A?

Comment: i update and insert git status. when i try `git add -A` also get permission message.

Comment: @MBehtemam have you committed your changes after doing the first pull? Does this status reflect that?

Comment: @gravetii i don't remember.maybe this status is reflect commits.i don't know.

Comment: @MBehtemam try rebasing with your master branch. `git rebase origin/master` or whatever your remote is and then try pushing.

Comment: Actually seems to me like a permission issue rather than an issue with git. Can you modify the log file with an editor? Can you create files?